# return render sends to correct location but no data until page reload?

Tags: django

I have a timeclock app for employees to check-in/check-out with which works ok, however when you're on the user-activity page and either check in or check out once it submits the form it sends you back to the user-activity.html page, but no data is loaded in the table and its not loading data from the view. Once you refresh the page the data is there again but I'm not sure why this is happening. I'll attach 2 images, one before the checkin/checkout button is pressed, and one after

and here is my view. Thanks for any help you can give

```
class ActivityView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        toggle = UserActivity.objects.current(request.user)
        user_data = UserActivity.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
        current_users = UserActivity.objects.order_by('user', '-timestamp').distinct('user')

        context['toggle'] = toggle
        context['user_data'] = user_data
        context['current_users'] = current_users
        return render(request, "administration/timesheets/user-activity.html", context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        toggle = UserActivity.objects.toggle(request.user)
        context['toggle'] = toggle
        return render(request, "administration/timesheets/user-activity.html", context)
```

[image: Before checkin/checkout button is pressed]

[image: After checkin/checkout button is pressed]

**EDIT**

Also here is my model...

```
USER_ACTIVITY_CHOICES = (
('checkin', 'Check In'),
('checkout', 'Check Out'),
)

class UserActivityManager(models.Manager):

    def current(self, user):
        current_obj = self.get_queryset().filter(user=user).order_by('-timestamp').first()
        return current_obj

    def toggle(self, user):
        last_item = self.current(user)
        activity = "checkin"
        if last_item is not None:
            if last_item.timestamp <= tz.localize(datetime.datetime.now()):
                pass
            if last_item.activity == "checkin":
                activity = "checkout"
        obj = self.model(
                user=user,
                activity=activity
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj

class UserActivity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='checkin', choices=USER_ACTIVITY_CHOICES)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_delta = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default='0.00', blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UserActivityManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.activity)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.activity)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User Activity'
        verbose_name_plural = "User Activities"

    def next_activity(self):
        next = "Check in"
        if self.activity == "checkin":
            next = "Check out"
        return next

    @property
    def current(self):
        current = 'Checked Out'
        if self.activity == 'checkin':
            current = "Checked in"
        return current

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user:
            user_activities = UserActivity.objects.exclude(
                                id=self.id
                            ).filter(
                                user = self.user
                            ).order_by('-timestamp')
            if user_activities.exists():
                recent_ = user_activities.first()
                if self.activity == recent_.activity:
                    message = "%s is not a valid activity for this user" %(self.get_activity_display())
                    raise ValidationError(message)
            else:
                if self.activity != "checkin":
                    message = "%s is not a valid activity for this user" %(self.get_activity_display())
                    raise ValidationError(message)

        return super(UserActivity, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your post function, I think you have a typing mistake :

```
toggle = UserActivity.objects.toggle(request.user)
```

I think that instead, you need :

```
toggle = UserActivity.objects.current(request.user)
```

Comment: No, toggle is a method in my extended model manager. Thanks though

Comment: Try to print toggle (from the post) and see if it prints anything at all

Comment: its posting ok, and its actually loading the toggle data in the get method ok too (otherwise it wouldnt be showing the checkin/checkout button after a post) but for some reason its not showing the user_data or the current_users once you do a post, until you refresh. Once you refresh the page or navigate to the page again then it shows all the post data as it should be

Comment: I needed to add the other context variables in to the post method. I was under the assumption that when it return rendered the request it would just load the data from the get method, and since the toggle variable was the only object that i wanted to post data with i thought it was ok to just have that in my post method